# How can I store/retrieve information in RAM instead of DISK

Tags: python, file, memory, ram

It is known for reading/writing files to do like this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fp: # reading
   contents = fp.read()
```

But how can I do that with RAM? Specifically write/read information from RAM not FILES.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206670/discussion-on-question-by-slhd-how-can-i-store-retreive-information-in-ram-inste).

Comment: @BhargavRao You've basically moved everything telling the OP that what he wants is at best underspecified, at worst not possible.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign variables in your Python program you are writing to RAM(including dictionaries). When you access those values you are reading from RAM.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for

Comment: sorry, your question is not clear. You can't store something long term in RAM as when you shutdown the machine all value in the RAM is erased.